# ¿Como acceder a un elemento dentro de una lista?

Tags: c++

Estoy aprendiendo a usar templates de C++ del `stl` y esta libreria contiene una clase `list<T>`, tengo entendido que tiene funciones parecidas a las de `vector<T>` *(De ser lo contrario porfavor ilustrenme)*.

Mi pregunta es, como puedo acceder a un elemento dentro de un objeto de tipo `list<T>` en un determinado indice?

Hasta ahora he intentado esto:

```
std::list<int> Numeros = /* Mi asignación aquí */;
int n = Numeros[0]; // Error.
```

Sin embargo, usando `std::vector<T>` funciona perfectamente:

```
std::vector<T> Numeros = /* Alguna asignación */;
int n = Numeros[0]; // Asumiendo que tenemos un elemento aquí, me devuelve el valor.
```

Es posible acceder a los valores contenidos dentro de un `list<T>` utilizando un indice?

Comment: Según veo en su [documentación](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/), se implementa una lista doblemente enlazada, por lo cual no posee una manera de acceder a un elemento en específico. Lo que debes hacer es acceder al primer elemento y luego recorrer la lista hasta que obtengas el enésimo elemento.

Comment: Simplemente iteraría lo que ya está dentro de la lista, no?

Comment: Así es.........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aunque todos los contenedores de la stl guardan ciertos parecidos en cuanto al uso lo cierto es que cada uno internamente funciona de forma diferente, luego no todos los métodos van a estar disponibles en todos los contenedores.

- `std::vector` representa una lista desordenada de elementos. Su principal característica es que todos los elementos están contiguos en memoria lo que permite el acceso aleatorio. Es el contenedor por defecto para la mayoría de las situaciones.
- `std::list` representa una lista enlazada. Al ser una lista enlazada Sus elementos no tienen por qué estar contiguos en memoria sino que para acceder al segundo elemento ántes has de acceder al primero. Es por este último motivo por el que no admite el acceso aleatorio aunque sí admite el secuencial.

Tradicionalmente los contenedores de la STL se pueden recorrer de forma universal usando iteradores:

```
for( auto it = contenedor.begin(); it != contenedor.end(); ++it )
{
  // ...
}
```

También existen funciones dentro de la STL que intentan encapsular un poco esta mecánica:

- `std::foreach`: Recorre un contenedor y, para cada elemento, ejecuta una función pasada por parámetro
- `std::transform`: Recorre un contenedor y, para cada elemento, ejecuta una operación pasada por parámetro. El resultado de dicha operación se almacena en un nuevo contenedor
- `std::find`: Recorre un contenedor buscando un elemento pasado por parámetro. Devuelve un iterador al elemento o, de no encontrarse el mismo, el iterador dado por `contenedor.end()`
- `std::find_if`: Similar al anterior pero admite un puntero a función que implemente el criterio de búsqueda
- `std::reverse`: Invierte los valores que se encuentren entre los iteradores pasados como parámetro (ojo, en contenedores ordenados, como `set` no van a funcionar)
- ...

Desde C++11 también está disponible un nuevo tipo de bucle que permite iterar fácilmente sobre contenedores evitando el uso de iteradores:

```
std::vector<int> lista(10);
std::iota(lista.begin(), lista.end(), 1);

for( auto item : lista )
  std::cout << item << std::endl;
```

También, desde C++11, están disponibles `std::begin` y `std::end`. Estas dos funciones permiten obtener los iteradores correspondientes tanto en contenedores de la STL como en arreglos de tamaño fijo (se puede calcular su tamaño en tiempo de compilación):

```
std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
int arreglo[] = {6,7,8,9,10};

for( auto it = std::begin(v); it != std::end(v); ++it )
  std::cout << *it;
for( auto it = std::begin(arreglo); it != std::end(arreglo); ++it )
  std::cout << *it;
```

Otros mecanismos para trabajar con iteradores son:

- `std::distance`: Calcula el número de elementos que hay entre dos iteradores
- `std::next`: Permite avanzar un iterador n posiciones
- `std::advance`: Similar al anterior, modifica el iterador pasado como parámetro

Bueno, todo lo anterior era un poco de teoría acerca de los contendores y sus posibilidades. Respondiendo ahora a tu pregunta, sí, es posible acceder a una posición en concreto tanto de un `std::list` como de cualquier otro contenedor haciendo uso de los iteradores y de `std::next` o `std::advance`.

En el caso concreto de `std::list`, no es posible acceder a un elemento concreto usando el operador de indización `[]` porque sus elementos no están en posiciones consecutivas de memoria. Acceder a un elemento aleatorio implica recorrer una parte de los nodos de la lista y esa tarea es realizada por iteradores y toca realizarla de forma explícita.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

He vagado por la documentacion del `stl` y algunas [preguntas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5733905/5622844) de SO, me he encontrado con `std::advance()` y `std::next()`:

- `std::next(Vector, Numero)`: Devuelve un puntero dentro del indice *(Parametro)* `Numero` de manera asignable, retorna un elemento del mismo tipo del vector. [Documentación](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next), cabe mencionar que sin el parametro `Numero` esta funcion avanza al siguiente elemento del Vector, por lo que este parametro es opcional.
- `std::advance(Vector, Cantidad)`: Funciona practicamente igual que `std::next()` salvo que este modifica directamente el parametro `Vector` por el elemento  ubicado en la posición `Cantidad` y no retorna ningun valor. [Documentación](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)

Ejemplo con `std::next(V,N)`:

```
int main() 
{
    std::list<int> v{ 2, 8, 5, 6 };

    auto Iterator = v.begin(); // El valor inicial (begin) es: 2
    auto Siguiente = std::next(Iterator); // El valor de Siguiente es: 8
    auto SaltaTres = std::next(Iterator, 3); // El valor es: 6

    std::cout << *Iterator << ' ' << *Siguiente << ' ' << *SaltaTres;
    return 0;
}
```

Ejemplo con `std::advance(V,N)`:

```
int main() 
{
    std::list<int> v{ 2, 8, 5, 6 };
    auto Param = v.begin();

    std::advance(Param, 2); 
    // El valor de Param fué alterado por el nuevo valor que le asignó advance(); 
    // Por lo que ahora Param tiene el valor de: 5

    std::advance(Param);  // Error.
    std::cout << *Param;
    return 0;
}
```

Cabe mencionar que el parametro `Cantidad` que he nombrado en `std::advance()` es obligatorio.

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(std::list<int>::iterator list_iter = int_list.begin(); 
        list_iter != int_list.end(); list_iter++){

        std::cout<<*list_iter<<endl;

}
```

`int_list.begin()` coloca un apuntador al inicio de la lista

`int_list.end()` es un apuntador al final de la lista

El apuntador al inicio de la lista se mueve al siguiente elemento con aritmetica de punteros: `list_iter++`

Comment: Por favor agrega una explicación al código, de lo contrario simplemente es un comentario.